# Laravel page could not be found when file request , in nginx centos7

Tags: laravel, nginx, server, centos, config

the routes of Laravel project in centos7 server with nginx are working but any file requesting from my upload directory in public returns "the page you are looking for could not be found." my API is ok , just file urls are not work.
font-end project is angularjs in root directory and laravel back-end is in core folder.
server config :

```
 server {
listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/core/public;
    #root /var/www/html;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/;
            #index index.html;
            #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
    }

location /api{
            #alias /usr/share/nginx/html/core/public;
            #index index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
location /upload{
            root /usr/share/nginx/html/core/public/upload;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }


location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

#location ~ /\. {
            #deny all;
    #}
 }
```